# How to mine ether from a private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, smart-contract-wallets

I launched a private network by using `geth --datadir data/node1 --http --dev --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net,miner --allow-insecure-unlock --mine` command.

I am able to attach to it `geth attach http://localhost:8545`

but the balance of the default account is only 1.15 ether:

`> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) 1.15792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457582226449518702905e+77`

I'd like to give it more ethers so I run:

```
> miner.start()
null
```

And I can see there is a warn in the node log: `WARN [11-27|21:54:32.983] Block sealing failed                     err="sealing paused while waiting for transactions"`.

I wonder what the issue could be?

Comment: I think geth launch in `dev` mode (parameter `--dev`) only mines on demand, when there are pending transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To start mining do `miner.start(1)`